# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use on windows machine

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am facing the following error on my window machine.

```js
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1733:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1781:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1869:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Tools\Stark\Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Tools\Stark\Server\app.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1760:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

From my research, most of them recommend either changing the port number or killing the port with target pid.

So, I changed the port number first - no luck..
And then, I got the pid and killed the port with the cmd:

1. `netstat -a -o -n`
2. `taskkill /f /pid [your target pID]`

However, I am still getting the same error after both attempts..

Any advise, please?